# How to optimally clear down multiple tables in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a script that will be clearing down 10+ tables that will be run frequently.

However, 3 of these tables have tens of thousands of records and this causes the script to take over 2 and a half hours to run. This isn't good enough because it will be run during the workday to test a suite of scripts that are migrating data.

We have tried a few different approaches:

1. `DELETE FROM x`

> Requires nulling some foreign keys but this is the most reliable way we have found. However, like I've mentioned, the runtime is far too long for our purposes.

2. A mixture of `DELETE FROM x` and `TRUNCATE TABLE x`

> This is the fastest way we've found. Deleting tables as normal and then truncating the problematic tables. But this requires an explicit order to clearing down the tables. This is awkward in and of itself but our DB schema is also changing frequently which makes this cumbersome.

3. Disable constraints and then `TRUNCATE TABLE x`

> We have also began writing a script to disable all PK/FK constraints related to the tables we would like to empty, truncate those tables and their child/sibling/parent tables, and then reenable those constraints. This seems like a good approach but is likely overengineering.

There is one further approach that I have considered but I'm not sure would it make a difference. This would be removing all FK constraints and adding a `ON DELETE CASCADE` to them. This might hopefully optimise approach 1. But I said I would throw it to SO first and see if anybody else has had to deal with this before.

Comment: Do you have indexes on FK constraints columns? - on the child table, of course. On the parent table the index is mandatory anyway.

Comment: What are the conditions for deleting? [Reference Partitioning](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-54D18B18-6838-4115-9389-E1FB0D20A8CA.htm) could be an option

Comment: You don't have to disable PKs, just FKs, and be sure to re-enable them afterwards. If your model changes over time, you can write a PL/SQL procedure to do the disable, then truncate and then re-enable. This way you can loop over user_constraints, the the 'R' ones, disable them using execute immediate, then loop over your tables, truncate them also using execute immediate, and re-enable the FKs in the same manner as you disabled them. Be sure to have proper exception handling in place.

Comment: Be aware, while constraints are disabled, the application my insert inconsistent data.

Comment: If you also need to clear the data in all (grand)child tables, then `truncate table your_table cascade` might be an option.

Comment: It should not take 2.5 hours to delete "tens of thousands" of rows.  Something else is going on.  I'd diagnose and solve that before moving to `TRUNCATE`.  `TRUNCATE` is not transactional, and that can cause problems if you are in a multi-user system and are not careful.  I would post more details of your problem/process before accepting answers.

Answer (score 2):

The TRUNCATE statement is way faster than the DELETE statement to empty a table.

In Oracle (as in PostgreSQL), there is a CASCADE option on TRUNCATE statement (as on DELETE statement), which might help about the "overengineering" part (when you want to disable FK, then reable them).

```
TRUNCATE TABLE x CASCADE;
```

Answer (score 1):

Truncating is better than deleting, especially for large tables. As you already found out, it is *faster*, but it also *resets* the high water mark so queries you run afterwards will run better.

Whichever option you choose (2 or 3) is OK with me, as long as you pick the one you prefer better. Knowing the order matters, so - yes, that's kind of *tedious*.

I wouldn't remove foreign key constraints; they exist for reason. If you do remove them, don't forget to recreate them afterwards.

---

You didn't say whether there are other tables involved in that schema. If not, perhaps you could even drop/create **user** and then recreate tables within the same script. Drawback: "normal" users can't do that, you'll need someone with DBA privileges.